# Echo from KornShell script not showing in terminal

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I have a KornShell (ksh) script that should be showing the `echo` after it is ran from the prompt.

```
#!/bin/ksh

file="file_path"

if [ -s $file ]
    then
        echo "yes"
    else
        echo "no"
fi
```

However, the "yes" or "no" are not showing. I have other scripts in a different directory that have similar if statements that output correctly to the prompt.

Any ideas?

Comment: Works for me (output is `no`) - which `ksh` are you using (`ksh --version`)?

Comment: I am using version: 93t+

Comment: Same here. As said, works for me ... Copy&paste the code from the question into a file, set execute bit, and call the script ... output is `no`

Comment: That worked. So odd, I should have tried that I guess. It just threw me off that it was working elsewhere and I speculated that something had changed to cause it. Thank you @Andreas.

Comment: @Andreas how can I give you credit for helping me answer this problem?

Comment: never mind ;-) you can upvote the answer from @javaPlease42 which describes the same approach I took...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute `chmod +x example.ksh` or `chmod 0755 example.ksh` for the script to be executable.

The KornShell (ksh) script itself works fine.

**example.ksh:**

```
#!/bin/ksh

file="file_path"

if [ -s $file ]
    then
        echo "yes"
    else
        echo "no"
fi
```

**example.ksh Output:**

```
@:/tmp #chmod 0755 example.ksh
@:/tmp #ksh example.ksh
no
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you call your script "test" ?
Test is a ksh function, rename your file or call it with

```
./test
```

Comment: Yes, I believe it was called "test". When I made a new file it solved the problem.